# Unexpected token colon JSON after jQuery.ajax#get

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have created a minimalist API on *nodejs* which return data in JSON format.

But every time I try to make a ajax#get call and pass my API as URL, I will get an error and judging from Chrome,  I'm getting a `"Unexpected token :"` error;

here the server code in *nodejs* + *express*:

```
var
 http    = require( 'http' ),
 express = require( 'express' ),
 app      = express(),
 server  = http.createServer( app );

app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( 'req received' );
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end( JSON.stringify({
    Name : "Tom",
    Description : "Hello it's me!"
    }) );

});

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log( 'Listening on 3000' );
});
```

The JSON returned from `"/"` is: `{"Name":"Tom","Description":"Hello it's me!"}`.

Here is my call from the client js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: findUrl,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function ( data ) {
        self.name( data.Name );
        self.description( data.Description );
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

When plotting the error I get: `"jQuery111108398571682628244_1403193212453 was not called"`

Can someone help me?

I know this question has been asked already but I haven't manage to find a solution which fix my program.

Comment: Check your `dataType` - [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Andreas : I guess you refer to "jsonp", I changed it to "json". I am now getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To support [JSONP requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_JSONP_works), the server will have to include the `P`, or "*Padding*," in the response.

```
jQuery111108398571682628244_1403193212453({"Name":"Tom","Description":"Hello it's me!"})
```

The syntax error, `"Unexpected token :"`, is because JSONP is parsed as JavaScript, where `{...}` also represents [blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). It just takes advantage of JSON and JavaScript's similar syntax to define the data being passed to a global function call.

By default, jQuery will include a `callback` query-string parameter with the name of the function:

```
var callback = req.query.callback;
var data = JSON.stringify({
    Name : "Tom",
    Description : "Hello it's me!"
});

if (callback) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    res.end(callback + '(' + data + ')');
} else {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(data);
}
```

ExpressJS also includes [`res.jsonp()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.jsonp) that already implements this condition:

```
app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( 'req received' );

    res.jsonp({
        Name : "Tom",
        Description : "Hello it's me!"
    });
});
```

Comment: The link in your answer to JSONP requests is broken.  Please update.

Answer (score -3):

You want to use dataType: "json" instead of "jsonp"

Comment: there are different reasons why you want to use jsonp, one example is to be able to call across different domains

Comment: agreed, jsonp is for CORS, you can't just use json if you need to make a cross domain async request via javascript.

Comment: JSONP is not for CORS. JSONP is the hack we used before CORS was developed and supported by browsers.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that's what I meant. JSONP is for when you cannot use CORS.