# jquery + jsonp return syntax error even when the response is json

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Why does this return a syntax error?

http://jsfiddle.net/syng17fv/

jquery.jsonp
https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp

response
http://cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk

```
$.jsonp({
    url : 'http://cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk',
    success : function(json){
        console.log('success')
    },
    error : function(){
        console.log('err')
    }
});
```

## update

This works

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        url : '//cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk',
        success : function(res){

        }
    });
```

Comment: [Have you checked google?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311023/unexpected-token-colon-json-after-jquery-ajaxget)

Comment: do you have a solution?

Comment: yes he does, right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311023/unexpected-token-colon-json-after-jquery-ajaxget

Comment: @Shea the error is with the JSON string, not the method of retrieval, answer would be the same either way.

Comment: could you then tell my why `$.ajax()` works with the same url? have updated my question

Comment: So, the question is: why the plugin doesn't work?

Comment: yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your api should respond with callback......i.e. callback appended to json string.  eg. callback + '({"msg": "ok"});'

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a callback parameter. I'll explain exactly why below.

A JSONP call doesn't work without a callback. The data is loaded in a script tag, and if the code is not in a form of a method call, the result would just be an object that was discarded, and the success callback method would never be called.

> Why does [not using a callback] return a syntax error?

This is how your ajax response essentially looks like without the callback (e.g. http://cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk):

```
<script> 
{"vat":11618405,"name":"TESTRUP ... (snip)
</script>
```

Of course there is a syntax error in this JavaScript! :)

Here is the ajax response with the callback (e.g. http://cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk&callback=callbackFunc):

```
<script> 
callbackFunc({"vat":11618405,"name":"TESTR ... (snip)
</script>
```

Now that's valid JavaScript. The `$.jsonp` with call `callbackFunc()` in this example, and everything is right with the world.

---

The core elements of JSONP, or "JSON with padding", are as such:

1. A **callback** function defined on your site.
2. A request to the remote API via  tag

   - **Includes a special param** providing the name of your callback function
3. The response:

   - Is just Javascript
   - That consists of:

     1. A function call, the name of which you specified in the request
     2. The argument being the JSON data of interest
   - Gets executed immediately, as if it were called from your own domain

> This **callback** arrangement between you and the server, combined with
>   avoiding same-origin restrictions, is really the whole trick to JSONP

REF: [So how does JSONP really work?](http://schock.net/articles/2013/02/05/how-jsonp-really-works-examples/), and [Wikipedia: JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

---

Change your json code like this. Works like a charm. Notice the "callback" parameter added. JSONP expects this. Here is your edited JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/syng17fv/2/

REF: https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/TipsAndTricks.md

```
$.jsonp({
    url : '//cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk&callback=?',
    success : function(json){
        console.log('success')
    },
    error : function(){
        console.log('err')
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @clarkk, did this explanation indeed solve your issue? I hope this satisfies your question and if so, would you mind kindly accepting this answer?

Comment: The code on your fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/syng17fv/2/ returns `Refused to load the script 'http://cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk&callback=_jqjsp&_1488820133245=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"` That is in shopify environment which I do not have control.

Answer (score 1):

After analysing the plugin, `url = url.replace( /=\?(&|$)/ , "=" + successCallbackName + "$1" );` is not working so fine enough to `make the jsonp callback` so add some function to make it work, or try to change the regex to add the callback to the url.

Try replacing the `url = url.replace( /=\?(&|$)/ , "=" + successCallbackName + "$1" );` `in the plugin` with the below code.

```
function addCallback(paramName, paramValue, url) {

    if (url.indexOf(paramName + "=") >= 0) {
        var prefix = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(paramName));
        var suffix = url.substring(url.indexOf(paramName));
        suffix = suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("=") + 1);
        suffix = (suffix.indexOf("&") >= 0) ? suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("&")) : "";
        url = prefix + paramName + "=" + paramValue + suffix;
    } else {
        if (url.indexOf("?") < 0)
        url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
        else
        url += "&" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    }
        return url;

}

url = addCallback('callback', successCallbackName, url);
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bharathi038/syng17fv/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Seems `callback` option doesn't work. Just add callback parameter to url with default value ([_jqjsp](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/API.md#callback---string-_jqjsp))

```
url : '//cvrapi.dk/api?search=test&country=dk&callback=_jqjsp',
```

Comment: I beat you by 2 minutes! But you have a sharp eye too

Comment: Callback works. Check out my updated JSFiddle the OP supplied